# JSON Deserialization for dictionary with arrays

Tags: c#, json

I have a Python code that sends this JSON through MQTT.

```
message = {
        "name":"Alex",
        "date": 2021,
        "activity":["act1","act2","act3"],
        }
```

Then I receive and Deserialize it in a C# script

```
public void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    { 
          var Message = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
          Dictionary<string, string> MessageDICT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(Message);
    }
```

The keys `"name"` and `"date"` has no problem being deserialized into the dictionary. However the error comes with `"activity"` due it being an array. Where it states "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:[". I have seen methods where they deserialize it separately (where the array is sent in a different message), however this is not what I want. Is there a way I can deserialize the message as a whole?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag c# or python but preferably not both. It's confusing because the desired result would actually be coded in c#, not python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your dictionary declared as `<string, string>`, but "activity" is an array.  So this is why it does not work.

If you want to keep using a dictionary, then you can instead declare it as `<string, object>` and then it will work for any type of data.  But you will need to then check what Type it is before you later try to use it.

```
Dictionary<string, object> MessageDICT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(message);
```

You can then access it like this:

```
object first = ((JArray)MessageDICT["activity"])[0];
```

But if possible, you should try to use a fixed class for the data and deserialize that.
Otherwise, maybe a dynamic is better.

Comment: I see, now that its consider as an object rather than a string, when I try to equate it a to variable like:

List_Activities = MessageDICT["activity"];

it throws an error, tried removing the quotation marks as well and has the same result. How can I make this work so that I can access the object type inside of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Hi why not use a class to read the json

```
public class Message
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public string date {get;set;} //actually, this looks like an int the json, however...
  public string[] activity {get;set;}
}
```

usage

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(message);
```